# Extract hash no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o seguinte *Hash*

```
my_hash = {city: {id:1, created_at: '', name: 'test_city'}, 
           uf: {id:1, created_at: '', name: 'test_uf'}}
```

Preciso extrair alguns dados dele ex:

```
my_hash.extract!({city: [:id, :name], uf: [:id, :name]})
```

Retorno esperado:

```
{city: {id:1, name: 'test_city'}, uf: {id:1, name: 'test_uf'}}
```

Porque não funciona, qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isto?

Comment: o extract vai modificar o hash original e te retornar outro hash, é isso que vc quer fazer, ou vc só quer acessar os valores?

Comment: O que você espera como retorno? Dê um exemplo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com os valores esperados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma extensão no `ActiveSupport` que permite extrair chaves de uma `Hash`:

```
my_hash = {
  city: {
    id: 1,
    created_at: '',
    name: 'test_city'
  },
  uf: {
    id: 1,
    created_at: '',
    name: 'test_uf'
  }
}

my_hash[:city].slice(:id, :name) #=> { id: 1, name: 'test_city' }
```

Não é bem o comportamento que você quer, mas ele pode ser utilizado pra resolver seu problema da seguinte forma:

```
Hash[my_hash.slice(:city, :uf). { |k, v| [k, v.slice(:id, :name) }]
```

Esse comportamento poderia ser generalizado e encapsulado em um método da classe `Hash` da seguinte forma - conforme disponível no [makandra cards](http://makandracards.com/makandra/10631-slice-a-nested-hash):

```
Hash.class_eval do
  def deep_slice(*allowed_keys)
    sliced = {}

    allowed_keys.each do |allowed_key|
      if allowed_key.is_a?(Hash)
        allowed_key.each do |allowed_subkey, allowed_subkey_values|
          if has_key?(allowed_subkey)
            value = self[allowed_subkey]
            if value.is_a?(Hash)
              sliced[allowed_subkey] = value.deep_slice(*Array.wrap(allowed_subkey_values))
            else
              raise ArgumentError, "can only deep-slice hash values, but value for #{allowed_subkey.inspect} was of type #{value.class.name}"
            end
          end
        end
      else
        if has_key?(allowed_key)
          sliced[allowed_key] = self[allowed_key]
        end
      end
    end

    sliced
  end
end
```

Assim esse método poderia ser usado da maneira como você sugeriu.